# Cloudbees Jenkins Folders Plugin: Folder Name as Enviroment Variable

Tags: plugins, jenkins, directory, cloudbees

Is the Folder Name available as an environment variable similar to JOB_NAME?

For a folder; JOB_NAME contains the full path including parent folders.  I want the immediate parent folder as an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
FOLDER_NAME=${JOB_NAME%/*}
STAGE=${JOB_NAME##*/}
```

See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 0):

No such variable exists, but `$(basename $(dirname $JOB_NAME))` would give you what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion of `$(basename $(dirname $JOB_NAME))` combined with the [Environment Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin), you should be able to set such an environment variable by selecting **Generate environment variables from script** and then providing the **Script Content** of:

```
echo FOLDER_NAME=$(basename $(dirname $JOB_NAME))
```